# What is this silver type thing connected with PCB?

Tags: identification

This is very quick question.

What is this silver type thing connected with PCB?

[image: image attached]

Comment: That is a heat sink apparently attached to a power converter.

Comment: It is attached to the below side of PCB, then how it can interface with circuit.

Comment: through the PCB. When you look closely, you'll probably notice that it's a metal-core PCB and thus conducts heat pretty well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a  *heat sink*.

To be specific, it's an aluminum heat sink.

These things are necessary, because electronic devices produce heat, and that heat must be gotten away from the device. In this case, the heat is transferred over an enlarged surface area (hence the fins) into the air.